# liquibase-maven-plugin: как указать путь к changeLogFile, который находится в зависимой jar?

Tags: maven, liquibase

Дано:
 1. Есть два проекта на Java. Первый - это бизнес логика приложения. Второй - это классы модели данных, используемые в первом приложении. Также в нем содержатся скрипты миграции changeLog.xml.
Первое приложение содержит зависимость на второе и использует его классы.
 2. Подключаем в первое приложение liquibase-maven-plugin:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          **<changeLogFile>
            ???
          </changeLogFile>**
          <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
          <url>jdbc:mysql://${mysql.host}:${mysql.port}/${mysql.db}</url>
          <username>${mysql.login}</username>
          <password>${mysql.password}</password>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

---

Как в changeLogFile указать путь к changeLog.xml из зависимой библиотеки?
Liquibase лежит в src/main/resource/db второго проекта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось следующим: чтобы плагин liquibase установленный в проекте с бизнес-логикой мог обратится к changeLog.xml в проекте с моделью данных, нужно добавить его в зависимости плагина:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        // Путь от корня проекта model-project до файла liquibase.properties
        <changeLogFile>db\liquibase.properties</changeLogFile>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
     // Добавить model-project в classPath 
     <dependency>
      <groupId>model.project.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>model-project</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Удобнее будет использовать файл конфигурации, который следует поместить рядом с pom.xml*

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

*Файл с свойствами, к примеру, может быть следующим*

```
classpath=db/liquibase/bin/ojdbc8.jar
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
changeLogFile=path/to/changelog.xml
url: jdbc:mysql://${mysql.host}:${mysql.port}/${mysql.db}
username: USERNAME
password: PASSWORD
```

*Накат изменений по конфигу в Idea*

```
liquibase:update -f PROJECT_FOLDER/pom.xml
```